# Breeze throwing InconsistentCLRPropertyDefinition on an enum while having the same class on both sides

Tags: c#, breeze-sharp

We have been having the issue that when we request metadata it gives us this error `System.Exception: Metadata mismatch - values do not match between server and client for DataProperty: 'ApprovalState' on the EntityType: 'Approval:#DMS.Shared.Dto.Db' Metadata property: DataType`. Approval state is a flagged enum like this:

```cs
public EnumStatus.ApprovalState ApprovalState
{
    get { return GetValue<EnumStatus.ApprovalState>(); }
    set { SetValue(value); }
}
```

And this is how we get our metadata:

```cs
dataService = new DataService(httpClient.BaseAddress + rootApiPath, httpClient);
entityManager = new EntityManager(dataService);

dataServiceKpvl = new DataService("Kpvl", null) { HasServerMetadata = false };

entityManagerKpvl = new EntityManager(dataServiceKpvl);

entityManager.MetadataStore.AllowedMetadataMismatchTypes = MetadataMismatchTypes.AllAllowable;

var idClientNameSpace = typeof(ApplicationUser).Namespace;
var kpvlNameSpace = typeof(Kpvl).Namespace;
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

entityManager.MetadataStore.NamingConvention = new NamingConvention().WithClientServerNamespaceMapping(dic);
entityManager.FetchMetadata().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
        logger.LogError("FetchMetadata: {0}", t.Exception.GetBaseException());
});
```

It looks like it is not parsing the enums correctly to the frontend.